# Set C# file as startup file in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How can I set pure c# file as startup file in Xamarin forms? I can delete both `MainPage.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml.cs` and add follwoing code from [the `ContentPage` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms):

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ContentPageExample
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public static Page GetMainPage ()
        {    
            return new ContentPage { 
                Content = new Label {
                    Text = "Hello, Forms!",
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                },
            };
        }

        public App ()
        {
            MainPage = GetMainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

If above code is added to the `App.xaml.cs`, it works. But if I delete both `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` and then above code is added to a new file `App.cs`, there is an error

> The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in MainActivity.cs in Android project.

Comment: I works perfectly for me. May be try adding more details on your error.

Comment: Are you adding this to your forms project not your platform specific project?

Comment: @ryan-gaudion, Yes.

Comment: Maybe show us your file structure and a bit more info on the error

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can currently think of that this issue may arise is that the code depecited is not the exact code that's in your `App.cs`, but you let Visual Studio add a new class to which you add the code.

The problem is, that the default class template of Visual Studio for a class named `App` is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ContentPageExample
{
    class App
    {
    }
}
```

Please note that there is no access modifier (`public`, `internal`) on our class. But for classes the default implicit access level is `internal`, i.e. only classes within the same assembly can see this class and create instances of<sup>1</sup>, since `MainActivity` is located in another assembly it is not allowed to access `App`.

You can fix this, by adding an explicit access modifier to `App`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ContentPageExample
{
    public class App
    {
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *There is an exception: You can add the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to an assembly to allow another assembly to access internal classes and methods, but I'd advise you to use this rarely and definitely not in the present case.*

Comment: Seems OK if add using ContentPageExample in MainActivity

Comment: @WWW Okay, I was on the completely wrong track then. Good thing you managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a complete c# file as a startup of Xamarin forms Application. But make sure your startup class should be derived from the Application class of Xamarin.Forms. Since its a root page for the cross-platform application. So your startup class should be like below,

```
public class StartUp : Application
{
    public StartUp()
    {
        // Set your main page here.
    }
}
```

In Android, MainActivity class,

```cs
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new StartUp());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that you have to set a new c# file at the start-up of the application, let's assume it as "Test.cs". In the constructor of App.cs file located in the main project of your solution, set the new c# file "Test.cs" as Main page of your application mentioning the type of Page you using(as it can be a ContentPage or NavigationPage).
Check the below sample snippet.

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new ContentPage (new Test());
        }
```

If you using MVVM Pattern, then you have to register your ViewModel with the Class file in the constructor of App.cs file. Create the custom NavigationService which can navigate between pages & ViewModals, SetRoot(), Pops out pages & ViewModels.
And then override the OnStart() method of App.cs file & set SetRoot() for the new c# file.

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
        MainPage = new ContentPage { Title = "Test" };
        RegisterPages();
        RegisterModals();
        ModalPopping += ModalService.ModalPopping;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        NavigationService.SetRoot(new Test());
    }
```